# When i open file first time file is opened but if choose the second time same file not opened how to do it in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, fileopendialog

Firstly open file through open menuitem but when second time open i choose the same file it opened in new tab. my requirement it not opened in new tab and display the message file already exist.

Here is my code,

```
public class Open extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JTextArea tx;
int i=0;
public Open() {
initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Open.setText("Open");
    Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Open);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,   javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    final JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
        JComponent panel = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
            FlowLayout.LEFT));

    int returnVal=  jc.showOpenDialog(Open.this);
  String title;
    String sts;
   File file=null;
 if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
 file = jc.getSelectedFile();    
 JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
 if (jc.getSelectedFile()!= null) {
  tx = new JTextArea();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
     StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer("");
      try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

                 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    String t = str.toString();

    // tx = new JTextArea();

    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true);  
  title=file.getName();
  sts=file.getPath();

    tx.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
    //tx.setLineWrap(true);
    internalFrame.add(tx);
    i+=1;
    internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
    JScrollPane  scrollpane=new JScrollPane(tx);

             internalFrame.setTitle(title);
    tp.add(internalFrame);
    try{
      tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){      
    }
     internalFrame.add(scrollpane);
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            tp.remove(internalFrame);
        }
    });   


    tx.setText(t);
   try {
            br.close();
            } 

         catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }        
  }                                    
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                           UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new Open().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Comment: You need to associate the `File` with the `JInternalFrame`, use some kind of `Map`.  This way, you can check to see if the `Map` already contains the `File` and if it does, you can extract the associated `JInternalFrame` and make it active...or what ever you want to do...

Comment: You could try look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a ArrayList of AbsoluteFilepath , and remove them from list when internalframe is closed . I have updated your code.Please check and reply

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameAdapter;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Open extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JTextArea tx;
ArrayList<String> fileList;
int i=0;
public Open() {
    fileList=new ArrayList<String>();
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
 private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Open.setText("Open");
    Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Open);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,   javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    final JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
    JComponent panel = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(
            FlowLayout.LEFT));

    int returnVal=  jc.showOpenDialog(Open.this);
    String title;
    String sts;
    File file=null;
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    file = jc.getSelectedFile();
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    if (jc.getSelectedFile()!= null && !fileList.contains(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
        fileList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        tx = new JTextArea();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        String t = str.toString();

        // tx = new JTextArea();

        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true);
        title=file.getName();
        sts=file.getPath();
        final String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
        tx.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
        //tx.setLineWrap(true);
        internalFrame.add(tx);
        i+=1;
        internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
        JScrollPane  scrollpane=new JScrollPane(tx);

        internalFrame.setTitle(title);
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        try{
            tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){
        }
        internalFrame.add(scrollpane);
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
        internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
                fileList.remove(filePath);
                tp.remove(internalFrame);
            }
        });


        tx.setText(t);
        try {
            br.close();
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File is already open");
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new Open().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration
}
```